# Почему модуль python устанавливается не туда?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6

Хочу установить модуль vk для работы с `vk api`.
Пишу sudo pip install vk. Он устанавливает. Открываю pycharm, создаю проект с python3.6 а там он не видит модуль vk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти в всех linux системах команда `python` запускает второй python по умолчанию.

Такая же история и с `pip` запускает pip для второго python по умолчанию.

Для того чтоб запускать от третьего Python вам надо добавить 3йку.

```
sudo pip3 install
```

Или

```
python3 -m pip install <lib>
```

Только убедитесь что у вас установлен pip на 3м python.

В случае если у вас не установлен pip установите его.

**Debian (Wheezy и другие) и Ubuntu(Trusty Tahr и другие)**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**CentOS 7**

```
sudo yum install python34-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
```

**Или ручную установку**

> Скачать сам файл get-pip.py
>
> Запустить текущую команду в терминале от имени администратора:
>
> `python get-pip.py`
>
> В случае если `setuptools` не установлен , то `get_pip.py` установит setuptools

[Частично слизано с анг. стака](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: Не во всех Linux системах, в том же Arch `python` и `pip` запускают третий питон

Comment: @andreymal поправил , да у нас в докерах тоже по дефолту стоит 3.5, а на бубунте своей я все делаю через python3 , а для большей уверенности скрипты запускаю через python3 <python_file>.py

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, вы установили библиотеку для другого интерпретатора. Для того, чтобы поставилось к нужному интерпретатору, попробуйте запустить pip следующим образом:

```
python -m pip install <lib>
```

Так pip точно будет запущен от нужного интерпретатора.